# How to refresh tabs in ViewPager when reciving JSON file?

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I have 3 tabs in viewpager and I am using ViewPagerAdapter that extends from FragmentPagerAdapter. I want to refresh the tabs when I recieve the new json file.

The json file will be parsed in the `onCreatView` method of fragments(tabs), I don't know how to refresh tabs to get new data from json file and parse it again!

And I want to place the refresh code in the `onResume` method of main activity.

```
private void designOfTabLayout() {
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    if(viewPager!=null){
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    if (tabLayout != null) {
        tabLayout.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        this.setTabIcons();
        this.changeTabsFont();

    }
}



class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}



private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    teamsFragment=new TeamsFragment();
    dutiesFragment=new DutiesFragment();
    projectsFragment=new ProjectsFragment();

    adapter.addFragment(dutiesFragment, "Duties");
    adapter.addFragment(projectsFragment, "Projects");
    adapter.addFragment(teamsFragment, "Teams");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    // For Opening Team Tab First :
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);

}
```

Comment: Does the user click a button to get the new file? Or is it pull-to-refresh? Or the new file is downloaded at set intervals automatically? How do you want it?

Comment: No , it will execute by onResume method in the main activity. for example when user press home button and then a few seconds later comes back to the application

Comment: Did you try to call "notifyDataSetChanged()" on your adapter?

Comment: No , because i guessed it works for sqlite database and doesn't have any relationship with json file